# When is $ \sigma(n!-1) $ a perfect square?

Tags: nt.number-theory, divisors, sums-of-squares, divisors-multiples

I am looking for pairs of positive integers $(m,n)$ such that $ \sigma(n!-1) =m^2$, where $\sigma$ is the sum of divisors function. Examples occur with  $(m,n)=(12,5),(1,2)$.

**Question:** Are there others?

Comment: I can't help my curiosity. Could you say more about your problem?

Comment: Well you probably won't be able to look far, because factoring $n!-1$ is going to get very hard very quickly. What's the actual question? The answer might be "this is completely intractible" :-/

Comment: No more solutions with $n<60$.

Comment: No more solutions with $n<79$ but it's going to be slow going now...

Comment: mayeb it is an open problem if i'm true .

Comment: Sure. It's not hard to come up with open problems in number theory. Some probabilistic argument will say something, and then we get stuck.

Comment: No more solutions for $n \leq 100$. I found the factorizations [here](http://www.asahi-net.or.jp/~KC2H-MSM/mathland/matha1/matha105.htm).

Comment: There are 97 more $n < 1000$ for which we know the *full* factorization of $n!-1$. They can all be found [here](http://www.asahi-net.or.jp/~KC2H-MSM/mathland/matha1/factorial-.txt) and [here](http://www.asahi-net.or.jp/~KC2H-MSM/mathland/matha1/fact-1m.txt) (the lines without a $\texttt C$ in them have a full factorization). All 97 of these do not give solutions.

Comment: Numbers $k$ such that $\sigma(k)$ is a square are tabulated at https://oeis.org/A006532 – it is not even known that there are infinitely many of them (although this would follow from standard conjectures).

Comment: @ChipHurst Wow, you can find everything on the Internet :P

Comment: @Gerry, the OEIS article of Buekers et al claim there are infinitely many n whose sigma value is a square.  Gerhard "From Looking At First Page" Paseman, 2016.11.25.

Comment: Why are you interested in this problem?